# Running tests in parallel using TestNG and gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, testng

I am trying to run my TestNG tests in parallel but they seem to just be running single-threaded. I am trying to run them using IntelliJ 14.1.4 Community Edition with the default built in gradle wrapper and Java 1.8.0_45.

I've also tried using standalone gradle-2.5.

The test section of my current build.gradle file looks like:

```
test {
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    useTestNG() {
        parallel 'tests'
        threadCount 3
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
test {
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    useTestNG {
        options {
            parallel = 'tests'
            threadCount = 3
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
test {
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    useTestNG {
        options ->
            options.parallel = 'tests'
            options.threadCount = 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to use `'methods'` instead of `'tests'` because I was only running one test class, using `-Dtest.single=TestClassName`, expecting all the `@Test` methods inside that to be run in parallel.

The relevant documentation:

> `parallel="methods"`: TestNG will run all your test methods in separate threads. Dependent methods will also run in separate threads but they will respect the order that you specified.
>
> `parallel="tests"`: TestNG will run all the methods in the same `<test>` tag in the same thread, but each `<test>` tag will be in a separate thread. This allows you to group all your classes that are not thread safe in the same `<test>` and guarantee they will all run in the same thread while taking advantage of TestNG using as many threads as possible to run your tests.
>
> From: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you testng.xml you have made.

Refer below link:-

http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/12/02/testng-executing-parallel-tests/

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests

Comment: I don't have a `testng.xml` file. Gradle was creating it for me, turns out it was creating it correctly all along I just had the wrong expectation.